# Neo4j community edition restrictions and limitations

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I was working with janus graph but I it has alot of drawback. so I am searching for other graph databases like neo4j.

I Want top prevent the problems with janus graph for answearing this question will help:

- What is the restriction of Neo4j community edition
- Neo4j has the concept of composite and mixed index.
- Can I manage indexes easily like create/delete index.
- Can I perform contains operation as like in RDBMS.
- The drivers provided for c#, python.. can perform all type of queries supported by Neo4j
- Does Noe4j case a problem with the next scenario:

  1. creating nodes type and properties
  2. inserting data
  3. create index for the existing structure
  4. change the old node and relations structure by adding new properties or types
  5. create new index combining the old and new properties.

I faced these problems with janusgraph, so I don't want to re-start them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what the problems with Janus were - you don't mention them - but to answer your questions:

1. The best place to look is http://neo4j.com/editions/. There are no differences in terms of capacity or the Cypher language (except property exist constraints). What you do lose is things like Clustering and High Availability.
2. Neo4j does have a [composite index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/#create-a-composite-index) and composite constraints.
3. Yep.
4. I think you're asking if you can do the equivalent of `LIKE` in SQL? If so - yes - you have `STARTS WITH`, `ENDS WITH` and `CONTAINS` for strings
5. Yes, if you can write it in Cypher, you can execute it in the drivers.
6. Neo4j is schema-less, so this scenario has no problem.

Comment: the most important limit for me is the mentioned on the editions site [Neo4j Editions Comparison](http://neo4j.com/editions/.)
- Graph size limitations 34B nodes (et al.)
for the community edition! The accepted answer is therefore not 100% accurate.

Answer (score 9):

Neo4j Enterprise is free to use under its open source license. You can use it in production, the US federal government does already.  Neo4j.com won't help you find details on it.   Many people are not aware of this.

https://GraphStack.io has more info.

Comment: My response was meant as a comment not an answer, sorry about that.

Comment: You can use it in Prod., but it may not be prod. ready and run at your own risk. You cannot run it in cluster, also backup is not supported.